# How to send parameters to html file I am serving through Klein(Flask) application?

Tags: python, rest, flask, klein-mvc

I am using Klein to develop REST endpoints. (similar to Python Flask)
I am interested in how can I pass parameters to the HTML file I want to serve, if that is even possible.

```
from twisted.web.static import File
from klein import Klein
app = Klein()

@app.route('/', branch=True)
def pg_index(request):
    return File('./')

app.run("localhost", 8080)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a templating language such as [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs) or [Chameleon](https://chameleon.readthedocs.io/). You could return a dictionary and interact with the dictionary on the template.

[Klein's docs describe how to use Twisted templates.](https://klein.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#templates)

> Templates
>
> You can also make easy use of twisted.web.templates by returning
>   anything that implements twisted.web.template.IRenderable such as
>   twisted.web.template.Element in which case the template will be
>   rendered and the result will be sent as the response body.
>
> ```
> from twisted.web.template import Element, XMLString, renderer
> from klein import run, route
>
> class HelloElement(Element):
>     loader = XMLString((
>         '<h1 '
>         'xmlns:t="http://twistedmatrix.com/ns/twisted.web.template/0.1"'
>         '>Hello, <span t:render="name"></span>!</h1>'))
>
>     def __init__(self, name):
>         self._name = name
>
>     @renderer
>     def name(self, request, tag):
>         return self._name
>
> @route('/hello/<string:name>')
> def home(request, name='world'):
>     return HelloElement(name)
>
> run("localhost", 8080)
> ```

and [this](https://twistedmatrix.com/~glyph/sphinx-preview-11.0pre1/projects/web/howto/twisted-templates.html), which shows you exactly what you are asking for. To quote the first few paragraphs:

> HTML templating is the process of transforming a template document
>   (one which describes style and structure, but does not itself include
>   any content) into some HTML output which includes information about
>   objects in your application. There are many, many libraries for doing
>   this in Python: to name a few, jinja2 , django templates , and
>   clearsilver . You can easily use any of these libraries in your
>   Twisted Web application, either by running them as WSGI applications
>   or by calling your preferred templating system’s APIs to produce their
>   output as strings, and then writing those strings to Request.write .
>
> Before we begin explaining how to use it, I’d like to stress that you
>   don’t need to use Twisted’s templating system if you prefer some other
>   way to generate HTML. Use it if it suits your personal style or your
>   application, but feel free to use other things. Twisted includes
>   templating for its own use, because the twisted.web server needs to
>   produce HTML in various places, and we didn’t want to add another
>   large dependency for that. Twisted is not in any way incompatible with
>   other systems, so that has nothing to do with the fact that we use our
>   own.

Answer (score 0):

See [this sample](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/master/examples/twisted/wamp/app/klein/example2/server.py) for use Jinja2 templates with Klein.